# Unwrapping Jdbc4Connection from SessionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, grails, jdbc

I want to use *CopyManager* from postgres JDBC for one of my project. However I'm having a problem with getting an instance of this object from a sessionFactory in a Grails project.

This is my current approach:

```
SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (sessionFactory.currentSessionFactory as SessionFactoryImpl)
LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lcdsProxy = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(sessionFactoryImpl.connectionProvider.connection).targetDataSource
DisposableConnectionFacade dcFacade = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(lcdsProxy.targetDataSource.connection)
Jdbc4Connection jdbc4Connection = dcFacade.next.connection.connection
CopyManager cm = (jdbc4Connection as BaseConnection).copyAPI
```

I'm sure there must be simpler way how to unwrap JDBC4 connection from session factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately since the `DataSource` is proxied 3 times, to get the real implementation of the connection and Postgres Jdbc4Connection, you either need to dig down through the `DataSource` proxies, or the connection proxies. I'd use more idiomatic Groovy though and skip using the 'current' session factory, since the `sessionFactory` proxy will pass all calls to the real instance (plus I'm pretty sure that would fail in a WAR file since this is only active in dev to support reloading):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy

def lcdsProxy = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(sessionFactory.connectionProvider.connection).targetDataSource
def dcFacade = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(lcdsProxy.targetDataSource.connection)
def jdbc4Connection = dcFacade.next.connection.connection
CopyManager cm = jdbc4Connection.copyAPI
```

My preference would be to get the connection from the current session, not the current session factory, since that's what holds the connection, and one of those 3 proxies is a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` to ensure that the connection being used by the current session would be returned from the `DataSource` as a 'new' connection. So one approach there would be

```
def connection = sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()
def jdbc4Connection = connection.targetConnection.targetConnection.connection
CopyManager cm = jdbc4Connection.copyAPI
```

or if this is the only reason you need the `sessionFactory`, you could use `withSession`:

```
AnyDomainClass.withSession { session ->
   def connection = session.connection()
   def jdbc4Connection = connection.targetConnection.targetConnection.connection
   CopyManager cm = jdbc4Connection.copyAPI
}
```

or even skip that and go to the `DataSource` (dependency-injected with `def dataSource`) since one of the datasource proxies is a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`:

```
def connection = ctx.dataSource.connection
def jdbc4Connection = connection.targetConnection.targetConnection.connection
CopyManager cm = jdbc4Connection.copyAPI
```

Comment: Why just not use `currentSession.connection().unwrap(PGConnection.class)`?